# How does the Hebrew Roots movement handle Paul's statements which imply Christians should not be enslaved to the Jewish Law?

Tags: paul-apostle, mosaic-law, galatians

My understanding of the [Hebrew Roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_Roots) movement is that they celebrate feast days and more closely resemble Jewish traditions rather than "Christian" ones.  For example, most Christians would celebrate Christmas while Hebrew Roots would celebrate Hanukkah, though both believe in Christ as savior.  If I'm misunderstanding, feel free to set me straight.

My question is how the Hebrew Roots (denomination?) handles Paul's writings, since a lot of it seems to disapprove of following the traditionally Jewish practices.  For example, Galatians 4 says things like

> But now that you know God—or rather are known by God—how is it that you are turning back to those weak and miserable forces ? Do you wish to be enslaved by them all over again? You are observing special days and months and seasons and years! I fear for you, that somehow I have wasted my efforts on you (9‭-‬11) NIV

And verses 21 through 31 talk about being "children of promise" where those under the law are slaves to it.

Does the Hebrew Roots movement have an explanation for scriptures like these?

Comment: Romans 14:1-12.  It is all about intent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being a member of the HRM for over 20 years I thought I would weigh in on this. The HRM views this passage like this.

Paul was speaking to pagans in Galatia. 
The Galatian churches were composed mostly of members from a gentile, rather than Jewish, background. Paul made it clear that they were physically uncircumcised (Galatians 5:2; Galatians 6:12-13), so they could not have been Jewish.

This background is important in understanding this controversial scripture. In Galatians 4:9-10, Paul said that the Galatians were “turn[ing] again to the weak and beggarly elements,” which included “days and months and seasons and years.” Since Paul’s readers were from a gentile background, it is difficult to see how the “days and months and seasons and years” they were turning back to could be the Sabbath and other biblical festivals, since they could not “turn again” to something they had not previously observed.

This is made even clearer by the immediate context. In Galatians 4:8, Paul said, “When you did not know God, you served those which by nature are not gods.” By this Paul referred clearly to the idols of paganism.  So in conclusion, since this verse is not referring to Jewish holidays and or festivals it does not need any reconciling for the HRM.

Answer (score 3):

From what I gather, there are [degrees](https://jewsforjesus.org/publications/havurah/havurah-v04-n01/the-jewish-roots-movement-pros-and-cons/) of Hebrew Roots teaching.

Some believe in salvation 100% by the atoning work of Christ, while some believe in a combination of Christ's works and your works.

Some believe the Trinity is a pagan invention, while some understand Christ is the Son of God.

They tend to believe that even though you may be saved by grace, it is a sin to not follow Torah, including feasts, Sabbath, foods, etc.  They understand that Christ followed Torah and so should His followers.

So to the specific passage, [they](http://www.bulldozerfaith.com/curse-of-the-law-understanding-galatians) tend to believe it is misunderstood or mistranslated.  They [cite](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Hebrew_Roots/Restoration/Grace_%26_Law/Paul) the numerous other Pauline comments about the law.

Generally speaking, Hebrew Roots disavows the oral teachings, but instead focus on the written word (Torah).

Comment: "Some believe the Trinity is a pagan invention, while some understand Christ is the Son of God."  I don't see how these two notions contradict one another, such that you might believe one or the other.

Comment: The *Curse of the Law* article was quite informative and appears to come directly from someone that is involved with Hebrew Roots.  I think putting some quotes from the article into your answer would improve it (and be helpful in case that article ever gets taken down).

Comment: @MasonWheeler  well the qualitative difference would be answering if Christ is Very God of Very God or was there a time the Son of God did not exist but was created?  The Trinity would understand Christ Jesus as part of the Godhead (Son of God).  Some in the HR movement understand forms of adoptionism or arianism regarding Jesus.  Those are the unorthodox positions.

Answer (score 0):

The feasts were celebrated by Jesus himself. They are intended as s roadmap to both salvation and the end times timing. The feast of sukkot will be celebrated even after Christ returns. Paul did not impose those celebrations on the gentiles because many would have simply turned them into pagan rituals, such as the Catholic Church did by turning Passover into Easter. They were not a salvation issue.

What most Hebrew roots people reject  all traditions of men (in terms of pagan hilidays like Christmas and Easter) and return to the Jewish feasts in order to teach their children (and connect themselves spiritually). The seven feasts are the story of God's longterm plan. They are times of celebration set aside by God.

I do not know of any Hebrew Roots folks who try to insist that everyone celebrate those feasts. They just refuse to participate in pagan rituals. I do agree that all Christians should reject Christmas and Easter as the Bible clearly says that God commands we do not worship him as the pagans worship their gods or according to the traditions of me, as that is an abomination to him.

Jesus Christ (Yeshua) is the Passover lamb, born during the lambing season when the shepherds were out with their sheep, born with the other lambs that would one day, if without blemish, be brought into the house, cared for and loved, then slaughtered for the final meal so that its blood could protect the household from God's spirit of death.

I personally think it is more important that I impart those lessons to my kids than to give them Christmas presents or lie to them about some creepy, fat, stalker guy watching them year round then breaking into our house to eat our food and leave presents from greedy, satanic, corporate manufacturers and Hollywood shills.

The feasts, however, do teach about God, Christ and His return, which is why Hebrew Roots folks celebrste them. They are also a lot of fun.  Galatians 4, Paul  refers to people who have begun claiming tbe fiests MUST be celebrated, (perhaps under some claim of greater righteousness or even as proof of salvation). Such teachings missed the point of salvation through grace alone. In galatians 4,  Paul specifically discusses the children born of Hagar being born into slavery. The inference being those still adhering to the law, are slaves. (The orthodoxy who rejected Messiah and remain under ritual and law and animal sacrifice). Hebrews Roots folks celebrate the feists for understanding and to align their values with the rootsock (Judaism) and to give their families a focus while the rest of Chrisedom is supporting pagan holidays due to traditions of men.  Those who understand this will not arrogantly tell you that you must celebrate the fiests. That would be slavery to the law. However, the issue of keeping Sabbath is entirely different because sa bath was made for mankind prior to Israel ever existing. Many seem to teach there is no need to set that day aside for rest anymkre as that was a day abolished by Christ's sacrifice. Not sure any Hebrew Roots folks would agree Paul meant that.

Comment: This is a good rant about why the feasts are better than the mainstream Christian holidays, but that wasn't my question.  I'm curious how the Hebrew Roots folks deal with Biblical passages (such as the book of Galatians) that appear to advise against special days (among other Jewish customs).  Christmas and Easter are not relevant to this question, though we agree on some points.

Comment: I've edited my response to include a discussion of galatians 4. May God bless you.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is. It is about the spirit behind the celebrations of any gathering.
The devil understands the recent desire to dig into Hebrew. Because The Spirit of Truth is being poured out in these last minutes of the last days.
With the evil one knowing this, he has traps set all over the place.
And people with good intent and purity of heart can get caught up in the flesh of it.
The pride of it lies within typically the ones who are leading these type gatherings.
They are looking for followers and people who hold them in high esteem because they
are actual "Hebrews".
It is almost 100% flesh....
Which is the way it always is.
The enemy is crafty and understands human behavior and psychology.
What he cannot predict, understand or thwart are people who are lead by The Spirit.

They are mature and have grown in discernment, wisdom, and understanding. They hate the things of the flesh and will not be fooled by these things.
I like many have returned to my Hebrew roots, and by The Grace Of God have been quickly quickened in my spirit that all these movements are flesh.
I love so much that learning Hebrew has enriched my relationship, and understanding of God.

But, I do not agree... dare I say I stand firmly against returning to what was imperfect when the Perfect Has come.
I understand that the Sabbath day is an actual day. This year it is actually on Tuesday. And I have had some very special times on these days in particular.
Do I adhere to the specific rules of the laws....
What Yeshua has done in my heart through His Precious Spirit. He has written what
he wants and doesn't want on my heart. I have a relationship with Him and do what
He says. That is what Yeshua was talking about.

I have known thousands of "christians/churchians" and several HRM people, what I find is religion basically.
I don't see people who are filled with The Spirit of God. I don't see humility and meekness.
I don't see people who lay their life (possessions,time,money) down for others.
What I see, is heartbreaking.
It is flesh, and knowledge.... It is a lot of mental knowledge and emotions.
Not dead people walking in the life of the Messiah and loving each other like
the person to the left of them is just as important as their own life is.

So if someone celebrates a "holy day" or Keeps the "sabbath" I think God just says...
I have been tired of those things for millenia, I just want your heart and you to treat people exactly how you would loved to be treated...

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! This looks like just your personal thoughts on the question. It also looks like you would in general be critical of Hebrew Roots... please [edit] this to add quotes and references to published Hebrew Roots sources so that we can know this truly does reflect what the movement teaches.

Comment: While I can appreciate your thoughts on the matter, and we very well may share some similar beliefs in certain aspects, this does come across as a bit overly critical and possibly unfairly generalized.  Just as I know Christians from multiple denominations that falter in various aspects, I know HRM can seem a bit overly physical, hence the question to hopefully get a perspective from that side.  However, since asking, I've met some HRM people that seem (from a more traditional belief) more "normal".  So, it seems just like all denominations, there's a spectrum believers will fall on.

Comment: No David, No to the entire comment. What you have said comes from the mind. The carnal mind, psychology, philosophy, rationality what have they to do with God?

Comment: As The Dude might have observed "That's just like, your opinion, man” which is fine for a discussion forum, but not on a stack.  The [tour], [Help], [ask], and [answer] provide guidance on how to present a supported answer.